# Is $C([0,1])$ with norm of supremum a Lindelof space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $C([0,1])$ be the space of real continuous functions defined on the compact interval $[0,1]$ with the norm of a function in this space defined as its maximum. I know it is not a compact space, and the strategy I know to prove it is to construct a sequence of functions that converges pointwise to a non continuous function. I would like to find out whether $C([0,1])$ is Lindelof or not, but couldn't prove anything and did not find such information by a web search. Is there any characterization (or implication) of Lindelof (Hausdorff or metric) spaces in terms of sequences that allow a similar approach?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C[0,1]$ is separable by Wierstrass Theorem and any separable metric space is Lindelof.